# How to separate child element from parent in css?

Tags: css, menu

I'm triying to combine these two menus:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/25/overlay-effect-menu/

The first one will stay unchanged and the submenu in the second one will be used with it. But as i begin to change the css code and make these to merge, i always encounter a particular error. The "ul,li and a" properties of the "responsive-retina-ready-menu" effects the submenu that i take from "overlay-effect-menu" and i can not separate these properties. I mean it shows the submenu as it has the same style with the main menu. What can i do about it?

The one i have:

```
<div class="main clearfix">
                <nav id="menu" class="nav">                 
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 1</span>
                            </a><div class="cbp-hrsub">

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon"> 
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-services"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-portfolio"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 3</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-blog"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 4</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-team"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 5</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 6</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 7</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Menu 8</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

The one i want:

```
<div class="main clearfix">
        <nav id="menu" class="nav">                 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 1</span>
                    </a><div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                            <div>
                                <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h4>Utilities</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h4>Education</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <h4>Professionals</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"> 
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-services"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-portfolio"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-blog"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-team"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 5</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 6</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 7</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Menu 8</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you just post the related CSS/HTML and what you have tried, instead of asking someone else to make it for you?

Comment: I don't want anyone to do something for me. I just want to learn the way to seperate the style of the parent and child elements in css. In another words, defining a private style for the children elements and protecting it getting the parents style properties.

Comment: What I mean is to post the HTML/CSS code that combines these 2 menus. This way you have more chances to get an answer rather than expecting someone else to make this job or research what each menu is about. As a 1st thought, adding a class or ID to the child menu would do your job.

Comment: The code i have for what you said is useless because the submenu inherits the "ul,li,a" properties of the main menu, so i have nothing to show about it but some meaningless code. And as i wrote in the title here, my real question is "How to seperate child element from parent in css, and make it to not have the css properties of the parent element?"

Comment: you can use CSS `:not` when it comes to child `ul` or `li`. Also a child menu can be usually selected like `ul li ul li` when a parent can be selected like `ul li`. If you don't post an actual code fragment I doubt if you'll get an answer.

Comment: I have added the html part. The css part is the same one in the links.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my comments you need to specify the styles of parent and children elements separately.

For example, in order to set `list-style:none` to parent `ul`s you need the following CSS selector:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
```

To keep the default styling to children `ul`s, you need to add the following selector **after the previous one**:

```
ul ul {
    list-style:disc;
}
```

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NtUXF/) based on the HTML given in OP with minimal styling but illustrating the way you can style parent and child elements separately. (Note: Hover on Menu 1)

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem. Can you contact me on pm or something?

Comment: @Jenkins please describe what's not working. The purpose of SO is to help future users with related problems. So, try to be as comprehensive as possible with the description of your problem (including related code fragments, fiddles, screenshots, etc.)

Comment: The css properties of the parent elements still effecting the child elements. There is no change in my problem after i used your code. And the thing is i have nothing to show. But i gave the links. The full css is there. If you have time you can examine both and tell us what the problem is. Anything that i will write from now on will be pointless if you can't see the original code.

Comment: @Jenkins You said you combined 2 menus that you refer to at your OP. At least please post the live url were you combine these two menus. Not each menu separately. Especially not the reference to their demo pages. We're trying to help here but you're not helping.